# Rails 6 and Oracle 11 XE: Why is the schema/structure dump so slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oracle, database-migration, oracle-xe

I'm using Rails 6 with `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` adapter for Oracle 11 XE database.
At the beginning of the project I was working with Postgres, but due to customer requirements I had to migrate to Oracle.

My question is very similar to [Rails: rake db:migrate *very* slow on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592444/rails-rake-dbmigrate-very-slow-on-oracle), but it's from 11 years ago, i'm using the updated version of the adapter.

I know that after all migrations are applied to database then rake db:migrate calls db:schema:dump task to generate schema.rb file from current database schema. I only have one schema, with many tables (around 90)

The answer for the previous question was something like

> One way how to debug this issue would be if you would put some debug
> messages in oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb file so that you could identify
> which method calls are taking so long time.

```
== 20200820164111 RemoveSemesterFromProject: migrated (0.1347s) ===============
real    13m26,038s
user    0m5,494s
sys 0m0,401s
```

All migrations finished in an reasonable time, so I think the error occurs in the following action "db: schema: dump" but i don't have oracle_enchaced_adapter.rb neither oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb, so i don't know where to look at.

What can i do for improve this behaviour?

**[EDIT]:**

Time that takes when i run `db:schema:dump`

```
real    9m44,074s
user    0m3,701s
sys 0m0,327s
```

and this is the time that takes when i run `db:structure:dump`

```
real    21m40,073s
user    0m5,046s
sys 0m0,413s
```

Comment: You might run `db:schema::dump` on its own to see how long that takes. Could try `db:structure:dump` too in case that's quicker.

Comment: i'm gonna edit, thanks!

Comment: Oh dear. Perhaps the question should be "why is the schema/structure dump so slow?". Do you have a DBA for the database?

Comment: I changed the question and no, i don't have a DBA for the database

Comment: I think that if you don't have a DBA available then it might be best to move the question over to https://dba.stackexchange.com/, though you're likely to have to do a bit of digging an explaining about what the schema dumps are. Most likely in Oracle they are calls to the DBMS_METADATA package https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026, which might help you start off with a good question. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: thanks! i'm gonna do that

Comment: @Grizz: Did you succeed in making the migrations finish faster? And (if YES): how?